# PyMySQL Join Query is empty

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a query that works perfectly in plain MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `ls_matches` AS m
LEFT JOIN `ls_regions` AS r
  ON r.id = m.region
WHERE
 m.crawled = FALSE
```

I am using PyMySQL lib to make a query, but the "same" query is empty:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `ls_matches` AS m"\
            "LEFT JOIN `ls_regions` AS r"\
                "ON r.id = m.region"\
            "WHERE"\
            "m.crawled = %s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (False,))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        pprint(results)
```

Any ideas on why this is empty? W/out the `JOIN` it works perfectly, so the issue is somewhere with that I think!

Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: `sql` has no whitespace between `m` and `LEFT`, `r` and `ON`, etc.

Comment: Agreed with @vaultah: it looks like the query you run in Python is the same, but it isn't because the strings split with `\\` are concatenated _as they are written_, without any newlines added.

Comment: yep, that was it. Do you want to write an answer I can accept? Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can use `"""string""` for long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check errors.

How about this?

```
sql = """
SELECT *
FROM `ls_matches` m LEFT JOIN
     `ls_regions` r
     ON r.id = m.region
WHERE m.crawled = '%s'
"""
```

Python gives you the ability to have strings that span multiple lines.  Use the capabilities of the language.

I would also encourage you to use parameters rather than stuffing values into the string, but that is a different issue.